# External monitors not detected on Ubuntu

Tags: display, xrandr, hdmi

I recently was messing around with creating virtual monitors with [this script](https://github.com/dianariyanto/virtual-display-linux) and streaming them to my ipad to extend my display. I was successful in this, but I later found that afterwards I was unable to connect my laptop to a display via HDMI.

### steps taken

- I have tried using different HDMI cords and different monitors
- [I have tried uncommenting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436706/ubuntu-22-10-external-monitor-not-working) `WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and rebooting
- [I have tried running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246654/ubuntu-20-04-second-monitor-on-hdmi-port-not-detected) `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` as well as `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and rebooting
- [I have tried running](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436706/ubuntu-22-10-external-monitor-not-working) `xrandr --output HDMI1 --off; xrandr --output HDMI1 --auto --left-of eDP1`

### other information

Ubuntu 22.10 x86_64
CPU: Intel i7-7700HQ (8) @ 3.8
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 630
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 M

output of `xrandr -q`:

```
$ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 190mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1368x768      60.00    59.88    59.85  
   1280x800      59.81    59.91  
   1280x720      59.86    60.00    59.74  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00    59.90    59.82  
   960x540       60.00    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00    59.92    59.57  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       59.51    60.00    58.99  
   640x360       59.84    59.32    60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

`eDP1` is my laptop display, `HDMI1` is what I assume my external monitor would be, although I only started digging into this once it became an issue, so I don't know that for sure.

---

Any help with this issue would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

---

## EDIT / UPDATE

I reinstalled Ubuntu and now I can connect to monitors, but I never found out the original issue

Comment: Did a reboot fix this?

Comment: @MarcusMüller no, I ended up re-installing Ubuntu and that worked